# Бесконченая синхронизация проектов в Android Studio 3.4. Что делать?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Обновил Android Studio с версии 3.3 до 3.4. Однако теперь проекты при загрузке начинают бесконечно синхронизироваться, при этом никаких ошибок не появляется. Что делать?

Comment: Баг зарепортить https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs#developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

У меня по сей день такое наблюдается (студия 4.0.1).
Выяснил что gradle-демон не запускается когда к ПК подключен телефон по USB.
Отключаю-подключаю - всё стартует и нормально работает.
Не знаю в чём проблема, кривом драйвере или разношенном USB-порте
и какое отношение они имеют к запуску gradle-демона...

Может кому-то ещё пригодится эта информация.